# Module not found error. webpack not resolving path mapping in module federation angular application

Tags: angular, webpack-5, angular14, angular-module-federation

I am having an angular 14 application and a library in the same repo. I am using  "@angular-architects/module-federation": "^14.3.14" and introduced modular federation in my angular application.
I mapped my library path in my tsconfig like below:
"paths": {
"test/": [
"projects/test/",
"dist/test"
]
}

Before creation of the webpack file the above path mapping was working. But now it is throwing module not found error like below.
[compilerError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvNje.png)

Not sure if the webpack files is not able to resolve my path properly.

Note: Getting this error only when rendering the testlib component in app.html. Importing the module or any service file from the library is working fine.

I have uploaded a sample application in my git hub page-https://github.com/JP-Jagadesan/mfe/tree/master

Answer (score 2):

1. you should go to webpack.config.js of your project and add sharedMappings there

```
const {
shareAll,
withModuleFederationPlugin,
} = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
name: '...',

exposes: {
  ...
},

shared: {
  ...shareAll({
    singleton: true,
    strictVersion: true,
    requiredVersion: 'auto',
  }),
},
sharedMappings: ['test'], //<--this is the list of what you have in paths in tsconfig
});
```

2. I think multiple mappings for paths are not supported yet - but you can give a try